# Webpack runs out of memory

Tags: node.js, linux, memory, webpack, single-page-application

#### Scenario

I have a 500MB RAM build machine and I want to use it to build a JavaScript bundle using webpack.

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js
```

This worked fine before, but as the project grew bigger, I started running out of memory. I tried setting an upper limit for node, hoping that webpack will do something smart but nope.

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2048" NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js
```

#### Constraints

- Time it takes to build is not important to me. If we have to use the SSD for the build, that is fine.
- This is a Linux box, but I have no swap.
- I am happy for alternative solutions in my architecture, currently I output one single 1.6MB JS blob for my SPA.

#### Errors

Errors when running out of memory

```
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Error when I add restriction for node

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Any help or recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: additional info

```
"webpack": "4.6.0",
"webpack-cli": "2.0.15",
```

Comment: Error is `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question - but could you run your command with --max_old_space_size=4096 ?

Comment: Fair point, but not sure how to use it. Webpack claims `Unknown argument: max_old_space_size`. Updated the question with my version of webpack and webpack-cli. Must be noted that webpack-cli is what is not recognizing the parameter

Comment: This is my build command I use for production build on webpack version 4.20.2   "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p --progress --colors --display-error-details"

Comment: As a dirty and quick solution you can create a swap **file** instead of swap partiton. It will slow things down and sacrafice some storage place, but at least your system won't crash.

Comment: Setting the max_old_space_size in the command line has the same effect as setting it as an env var (with error in my description above)